# Import Error: no module named, after file moved to another folder

Tags: python, importerror

I recently moved a utils.py file into a utils folder. 
Folder structure:

```
+ v0
    -handlers.py
    -utils.py

+ utils
    -__init__.py
    -base.py
```

Now, I moved the methods in utils.py to base.py.

I am getting import error in handlers.py at:

```
from utils.base import *
```

Note: I deleted the utils.py file.

Upon debugging, I noticed that handlers.py is still looking up for utils.base in utils.py
That file is nowhere in my project anymore. I have no clue where this handlers.py, looking up for this utils.py file instead of the utils folder.

Comment: just to check, did you also remove all the pyc files?

Comment: Yes, I had removed them, then restarted the server, but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging via PyCharm or IntelliJ, you may need to delete the test run config for that test.